# UILongPressGestureRecognizer contine animation when state changed

Tags: ios, swift, animation

i have a UILongPressGestureRecognizer added on UIImageView. The purpose of it is if the user press on the image an animation should start. This is working perfect. But as soon the user moves his finger a little bit the animation stops. I know that this occurs because of the state which changed. However i would like to continue the animation and only to stop when the user remove his finger from the image.

So far my code for adding the gesture recognizer is

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("imageTapped:"))
    tapGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0
    barcodeImage.userInteractionEnabled = true
    barcodeImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

and the code for the animation is

```
func imageTapped(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{
    let animation : CATransition  = CATransition()
    animation.delegate = self
    animation.duration = 2.5
    animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    animation.type = "rippleEffect"
    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended){
        logger.log("press ended");
        // and stop animation
        barcodeImage.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }else{
        logger.log("show animation")
        barcodeImage.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

How can i continue the animation when the state changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
barcodeImage.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

---

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if (touches.first?.view == barcodeImage) {
        print("show animation")
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    print("removeAllAnimations")
}

override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    print("removeAllAnimations")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UIPanGestureRecognizer instead,

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("imageTapped:"))
barcodeImage.userInteractionEnabled = true
barcodeImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

func imageTapped(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{
    switch gesture.state {
    case .Began :
        let animation : CATransition  = CATransition()
        animation.delegate = self
        animation.duration = 2.5
        animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        animation.type = "rippleEffect"
        barcodeImage.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
        break;
    case .Ended, .Cancelled :
        barcodeImage.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        break;
    default :
        break
   }

}
```